# How do you download OSM maps to Garmin Edge?

Tags: gps, maps, garmin

How do you download free Open Street Maps (OSM) data on to an SD card for garmin edge 800 / 810 for use in navigation and turn by turn directions?

Comment: Unfortunately this won't be of help to you, anyone from the UK viewing this question can obtain free maps here: http://talkytoaster.info/ukmaps.htm

Comment: I can strongly recommend [OpenFietsMap](http://www.openfietsmap.nl) and [OpenMTBMap](http://openmtbmap.org) which are based on OpenStreetmap but heavily optimized for cycling. Map data contains information such as kind of track, ground, slope etc. and supports active routing (turn by turn directions).
You can find detailed information on exporting of maps and how to transfer to Edge in tutorials section of OpenMTBMap website. Give it a try!

Comment: DCRainmaker has excellent instructions on his site. http://www.dcrainmaker.com/2013/05/download-garmin-705800810.html

Answer (score 3):

You can get map files that work on Garmin devices (I haven't tried with Edge) from [this site](http://garmin.openstreetmap.nl/). You can select predefined areas (countries, provinces) of the world you want, or create custom selections of just your area. They generate a map of your desired area and send you an email when its ready so you can download it.

Comment: Had anyone tried with this and verified that the map and turn by turn navigation actuall work with this map set?

Comment: Haven't tried yet (maybe I will tonight if I have time), but the first set of radio buttons gives different options, one of which is "Routable Bicycle", which sounds quite promising.

Comment: Do these maps have POI?

Comment: I can confirm that these maps have lots of POIs and navigation works fine on Garmin Oregon 300 device. Quality differs by region, as it is anywhere on OSM.

Comment: @Benzo I've been using these maps (from Kibbee's link) throughout Europe for about 2 years on my 800. In terms of loading a route onto the Garmin, displaying the map and the device telling you when to turn, they work great. In terms of actually relying on the Garmin to plot its own route using these maps....I don't know.

Comment: Also worth saying that you can download several of these maps, and as long as you give the maps unique names on the micro SD, there's no problem with the device reading them (true for the Edge 800 at least). The map doesn't have to be called gmapsupp.img, you can have france.img, italy.img etc. if you wish

Comment: I have used these maps on an edge 810 without  any problems.